# Windows Service Thread.isBackground = true terminates application prematurely

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to create a windows service which periodically queries data from db and executing tasks based on the data. 
I used threading and the following code terminates immediately after I run it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
namespace MESUDeleteService
{
    public partial class MESDeleteService : ServiceBase
    {
        AutoResetEvent StopRequest = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        private Thread _thread;

        public MESDeleteService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void startConsole()
        {
            OnStart(null);
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            MESUDeleteService.Core.Logger.Writelog.Info("Deletion Service Start");
            _thread = new Thread(WorkerThreadFunc);
            _thread.IsBackground = true;
            _thread.Start();
        }

        public void WorkerThreadFunc()
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                if (StopRequest.WaitOne(10000)) return;
                try
                {
                    SNDX.DataAccess.UnitOfWork uow = new SNDX.DataAccess.UnitOfWork();

                    var deleteOrderCollection = uow.DeleteSettingsRepository
                        .Get()
                        .Where(m => m.STATUS == "ACTIVE" && m.NEXTRUN != null)
                        .Where(n => n.NEXTRUN.Value.ToString("{0:yyyyMMddHHmm}") == DateTime.Now.ToString("{0:yyyyMMddHHmm}"))
                        .ToList<SNDX.DataAccess.SND_DELETE_SETTINGS>();

                    if (deleteOrderCollection.Count > 0)
                    {
                        MESUDeleteService.Core.Logger.Writelog.Info("There'r new Delete Orders");

                        //process each delete orders
                        foreach (SNDX.DataAccess.SND_DELETE_SETTINGS x in deleteOrderCollection)
                        {
                            MESUDeleteService.Core.Logger.Writelog.Info("Delete Type : " + x.SETTINGS);
                            MESUDeleteService.Core.DeleteOrder deleteOrder = new MESUDeleteService.Core.DeleteOrder();
                            deleteOrder.Settings = x.SETTINGS;
                            deleteOrder.SearchPattern = x.SEARCHPATTERN;
                            deleteOrder.NetworkPath = x.NETWORKPATH;
                            deleteOrder.EmailList = x.EMAILLIST;
                            deleteOrder.ID = x.ID;
                            deleteOrder.LastRun = DateTime.Now;
                            deleteOrder.WeekRun = x.WEEKRUN;
                            deleteOrder.ComputerName = x.COMPUTERNAME;
                            deleteOrder.DomainName = x.DOMAINNAME;
                            deleteOrder.ADAccount = x.ADACCOUNT;
                            deleteOrder.ADPassword = x.ADPASSWORD;

                            //by having them in a thread.                            
                            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(deleteOrder.ThreadStart)) { IsBackground = true };
                            t.IsBackground = true;
                            MESUDeleteService.Core.Logger.Writelog.Info("Delete Thread Starting Type");
                            t.Start();
                        }
                    }
                    uow.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MESUDeleteService.Core.Logger.Writelog.Error(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            StopRequest.Set();
            _thread.Join();
        }
    }
 }
```

However, if I removed **isBackground=true**, it will run normally, but it will consume alot of CPU power.

With **isBackground=true**, the service/app terminates @

```
 SNDX.DataAccess.UnitOfWork uow = new SNDX.DataAccess.UnitOfWork();
```

How can I optimize this code ?

Comment: `IsBackground` has *nothing* to do with how much "CPU power" a thread uses. The only difference between background and foreground threads is that *background threads don't stop the process from shutting down if all other foreground threads have exited*. You're pressing *exactly* the button that says "shut down this process"

Comment: Which you would have found called out quite clearly if you had read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground(v=vs.110).aspx): "Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that background threads do not prevent a process from terminating"

Comment: I removed isbackground and let it be foreground.. however, the CPU consumption is 100% of the core it was assigned to.. What causes it to be 100%?

Comment: Well, I'd question the wisdom of spinning off a seperate thread for every deletion - what does it do if you just run each delete sequentially? Have you considered using tasks or the thread pool rather than creating ever more threads?

Comment: You could also consider changing the thread's [`Priority`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority(v=vs.110).aspx) to `BelowNormal` or `Lowest` and then they'll only be using 100% CPU if there's nothing more useful to be done on the machine.